# How do you manage versioning across platforms in Unity?

Tags: unity

I'm just beginning to look into versioning games in Unity and noticed that Unity seems to offer different things depending on the platform you are building for. For instance, Android and iOS seem to have their own individual properties for versioning while Desktop has no versioning functionality at all out of the box.

Since I'm working on a game that has builds for PC, Mac, Android, and iOS, I need to determine how we want to manage version numbers within our game without having to manually manage individual version for each platform. How do you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could make a build script which sets the version number at build time. So you have some place which tells the script what the last build was, then increment by one, update this file and continue with the build. You might have to tweak it for each platform with compiler commands but it would result in virtually automatic build numbers. If you want more information about the build you could get the build script to append an Excel (or Google Excel equivalent for easy sharing) sheet with more information (build time, failure message, who built the particular version of the game, etc) you can get really intricate with this

If you use a build server this would be extremely useful as it will do this everytime and you would be able to track bugs which what build they first appeared in which might help find which source control commit caused the error.

If you do use this it will keep builds in sync so when it comes down to managing the builds later you should know what changes happened since the last build and you can go from there.

Answer (score -2):

Well if your ready to write some code then just do this.
Make a website with FTP

Make a txt file on a FTP account called Update with the version number in it

Before starting game download this file.

Check if it is the same as a local version of the file.

If it isn't the download game-VERSION.zip and extract in game folder and delete txt and start.

Else delete and start.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. I'm only interested in how to manage version numbers within Unity for each build. Android and iOS appear to have their own versions as their respective app stores have versioning requirements.